# Multiple fields required in cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column that I need to filter by the following terms, A, AA and AAA. These represent time spans so some will cover multiple time spans, eg some will have A, AA or AA, AAA) but I want to still be able to filter them separately (eg I want to be able to see all A's, All AA's and all AAA's)

Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Please include some sample data and explain current and expected behaviour on that.

Comment: Have you tried using the advanced filter?

Answer (score 1):

Say we have data like:

[image]

First copy column **B** into column **C**.  Then in column **C**:

1. replace *AAA* with *C*
2. replace *AA* with *B*

[image]

Now we can AutoFilter column **C** with the *Contains* option to display any combination of criteria.